# How can I return the initial value in the pickerView [swift]

Tags: ios, swift2, uipickerview

In my project, the user will enter data into fields using a `pickerView`. Some of the fields will have very few values to choose from and often the initial value, or the 0th value of the source array, will be the desired value. However, when the `pickerView` appears and the 0th value is the initially selected value, the user has to select a different value, the select the 0th value in order for that value to populate the field. I hope that makes sense.

How can I allow the user to simply tap the field to bring up the `pickerView`, then, if the highlighted value is the desired value, allow the user to simply click the done button and populate the field with that value?

Here is my code for `didSelectRow`:

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    if activeDataArray == personnelName {
        enterPersonnelName.text = personnelName[row] as String
    }
    else if activeDataArray == drugID {
        enterDrugID.text = drugID[row] as String
    }
    else if activeDataArray == packageNumber {
        enterPackageNumber.text = packageNumber[row] as String
        enterQty.text = quantity[0]
        enterExpDate.text = expDate[0]
    }
    //put pickerView away
    //self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

I have looked through the Similar Questions list and have searched questions with different phrases but I have not found anything that seems to answer what I am asking. If I have missed the answer, please point me in that direction.

I appreciate your time and assistance.

Answer (score 0):

func selectedRowInComponent(_ component: Int) -> Int will tell you which item is currently selected in the picker view. The Done button should be connected to an IBAction that will find the row that is selected and then obtain the data from appropriate array (drugID or packageNumber?). Note you can also selectRow to preselect a default value for the user.

Answer (score 0):

OBJECTIVE -C

Add this to your `viewDidLoad`

```
[pickerView selectRow:2 inComponent:0 animated:YES];
```

`pickerView` is the name of your picker view

`selectRow` is which row you would like to preselect (of course start counting at 0)

`inComponent` is the component number if you have more than one component in the picker view, in this case, it is choosing from the first component (a component is a column f values in your picker view, if you only have one, leave this as 0 )